# Increment number by 1 in foreach loop upto 10

Tags: php, foreach, increment

I am trying to increment a value in a foreach loop, but I need it to be maximum 10. How can I do that? My current code is

```
$i = 0;
foreach ( $signatures as $signature ) {
    echo 'Signature ID: ' . $signature . $i;
    $i++;
}
```

Where this foreach loop should stop when the value of `$i` should reach 10.

Thanks

Comment: `if ($i == 10) break;` in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ( $signatures as $signature ) {
    if($i==10){
        break;
    }
    echo 'Signature ID: ' . $signature . $i;
    $i++;
}
```

Just use `break` if you want to end any iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Along with breaking the foreach loop at 10, you could just do a for loop:

If $signatures is a numerical array:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $signature = $signatures[$i];
}
```

If $signatures is an associative array, access with current() and advance with next():

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $signature = current($signatures);
    next($signatures);
}
```